# unable to get the result of query

Tags: mysql

I have data of 4 semesters in the db name,reg_no,sem,backlog,and department.
student will be eligible only if has no backlogs in 1st,2nd semester and the sum of 3rd and 4th semester backlogs are less the 4.

I want to fetch the records of students those are not eligible.

example:-data in the format of

```
name|reg_no|sem|backlog|department|
s1  |01    |1  |0      |cs        |
s2  |02    |1  |1      |cs        |
s3  |03    |1  |0      |cs        |

s1  |01    |2  |0      |cs        |
s2  |02    |2  |0      |cs        |
s3  |03    |2  |0      |cs        |

s1  |01    |3  |0      |cs        |
s2  |02    |3  |0      |cs        |
s3  |03    |3  |3      |cs        |

s1  |01    |4  |0      |cs        |
s2  |02    |4  |0      |cs        |
s3  |03    |4  |3      |cs        |
```

I need the result in this format

the output should be in this form as s2 has backlog in semester 1
and s3 has the more the 4 backlogs.

```
name|reg_no|sum(blacklog)|department|
s2  |02    |1            |cs        |
s3  |03    |6            |cs        |
```

I am using this query.

```
SELECT reg_no 
FROM exam 
where sem<3 and reg_no In(
                          SELECT reg_no 
                          FROM exam 
                          where sem<5 
                          and department='dpt' 
                          and year='2018-2019' 
                          group by reg_no 
                          having sum(backlog)>=0 
                          order by reg_no) 
group by reg_no 
having sum(backlog)!=0
```

which gives me only the 3rd and 4th semester sum(blg) result only if it has the sum(blg)!=0 it does not give the result.

please help me out i apologize i am unable to describe my query.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe you could provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: The question is not clear could you please provide sample data.

Comment: Your query will never work as you have placed the order by clause inside sub-query. Please make sure you are posting exact query here. Also it would be more helpful for us if you post the sample data and expectd O/P here.

Comment: i have edited my query please let me know if it not clear